# Forming a Tsql query that ranks and categorizes date field

Tags: t-sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this datset:

```
create table #date_example
(
date_val datetime, rownum int
)

insert #date_example values('3/1/14',1)
insert #date_example values('3/1/14',2)
insert #date_example values('3/1/14',3)
insert #date_example values('2/1/14',4)
insert #date_example values('1/3/14',5)

select --top 1 with ties
date_val, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rownum ORDER BY date_val DESC) AS 'RowNum'

from #date_example
order by date_val
desc
```

With output:

```
date_val    RowNum
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 1
```

But I want instead output:

```
date_val    RowNum
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000 1
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 2
2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 3
```

So I want the RowNum to be a ranking which includes ties.  How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try RANK() or DENSE_RANK()?

Comment: PARTITION BY rownum  -  in the dataset rownum is unique.  And it is real confusing that you use rownum and RowNum - tsql is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from another post:

```
select 
date_val, 
Rank() OVER(ORDER BY date_val DESC) AS 'RowNum'

from #date_example
```

Comment: Interesting, you didn't see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633648/how-to-form-a-tsql-query-that-ranks-and-categorizes-date-field#comment41875027_26633648)?